# How to access other arguments from callback function

Tags: elisp

I'm using [emacs-request](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request) to get some json data from the web. Here's an example

```
(defun test (arg1 arg2)
  (request
   "http://httpbin.org/get"
   :params '(("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2"))
   :parser 'json-read
   :success (cl-function
             (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
               (message "I sent: %S" (assoc-default 'args data))))))
```

I'm wondering how the callback functions such as `:success` can have access to arg1 and arg2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the [`lexical-binding` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html#Using-Lexical-Binding) to `t`, allowing the lambda to have access to the outer function's arguments, or wrap the `:success` function in a `lexical-let` that binds the outer function's arguments for the lambda:

```
(defun test (arg1 arg2)
  (request
   "http://httpbin.org/get"
   :params '(("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2"))
   :parser 'json-read
   :success (lexical-let ((arg1 arg1) (arg2 arg2))
              (cl-function
               (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
                 (message "%s %s sent: %S" arg1 arg2 (assoc-default 'args data)))))))
```